# Transform dictionary to map values to list of keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

For example I have a dictionary like this:

```
my_dict = {
    'name_1': 'method_name_x',
    'name_2': 'method_name_x',
    'name_3': 'method_name_y',
}
```

(keys and values of the dictionary are simply strings)

I want to transform this dictionary so that all values will be mapped to a list of keys which have these value.

Example result:

```
my_transformed_dict = {
    'method_name_x': ['name_1', 'name_2'],
    'method_name_y': ['name_3'],
}
```

I could do this by the following code:

```
my_transformed_dict = dict.fromkeys(my_dict.values(), [])
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    my_transformed_dict[v].append(k)
```

But this will end up addind every key to the values somehow.

I also thought of using dict.setdefault(), like this:

```
my_transformed_dict = dict()
for k, v in my_dict:
    my_transformed_dict.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
```

This works as indentend, but:

What would be best practice to solve this?

Is there a simpler way to solve this (maybe using a library)? Or just doing the code as a readable one-liner?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I'm not I am not looking for a library directly. I updated the question to clarify the goal.

Comment: One liners aren't necessarily more readable or efficient than multiple lines. I would much rather see five lines that clearly demonstrate intention than one line that I'd have to spend ten minutes deciphering every time I come across it (provided performance isn't much worse)

Comment: The first method will set each value of the dictionary to the same list, which is not a feasible method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), for example:

```
from itertools import groupby

my_dict = {
    'name_1': 'method_name_x',
    'name_2': 'method_name_x',
    'name_3': 'method_name_y',
}
print({k: list(v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(my_dict, key=lambda k: my_dict[k]), key=lambda k: my_dict[k])})
```

**Output:**

```
{'method_name_x': ['name_1', 'name_2'], 'method_name_y': ['name_3']}
```

Comment: `groupby` requires an extra O(n log n) sort, which OP's approaches do not.